# Sentiment analysis with the help of word embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am doing sentiment analysis with GloVe and Fast Text word embeddings on a tweet dataset (using tensorflow & keras). I am trying to compare two models in terms of 'accuracy'. But each time, I run the Jupyter notebook, the accuracy keeps on varying. Sometimes the GloVe model gives better accuracy and sometimes the Fast Text model. What is the reason behind it? Is there any way to keep the accuracy of the two models constant.

Comment: Have you set a seed for both the scripts?

Comment: No, I have not set a seed. How is it done? Any example please let me know.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed

Comment: Something else is also changing with each run e.g. seed, splits of test/train etc. Share your code.

Comment: I have already used random state =42.

Comment: That random_state is for the train_test split I suppose, you also need to set a seed for your weights when you initialize your keras model. Also increase the iterations you are running the model for, I don't think you are reaching convergence.

Comment: I have put random seed before using the Tensorflow tf.  But it is still varying a bit. Also my model us having overfitting issue. So I have just 6 epochs.

Comment: Please provide a code sample in that case